# Integrate python turtle output into webpages

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, vue.js, web, turtle-graphics

I'm currently working on a remote teaching website that takes in python code and returns output through AWS lambda. A popular library that is used for teaching is python turtle, I want to be able to show the output of turtle inside my webpage, how should I do this? What I want to achieve would be how repl.it does it. Thank you for any pointers!

[repl.it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPaqb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a many ways to embed your Python code in your website:

Two simple ways:

1. Within your website, you could embed your python turtle code using Trinket, https://trinket.io/turtle, click on the Share button and select Embed option. Copy and paste the <iframe..> into your website. Trinket offers other libraries like pygame but at a cost.
2. For something more advance, explore Skulpt: skulpt.org. You can also embed your code, but if you want to learn how is done, check their repo and the JavaScript code behind it:
   https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt.